# Winforms: panel doesn't update/refresh content when scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, autoscroll, groupbox

I'm creating a windows forms with one groupbox and two panels:

[image]

In the first panel, I'm going to add and remove dynamically controls with the buttons add and remove from the second panel.

In the first panel, I set `AutoScroll = true`, so that when it has a lot of controls the user can edit them without changing the size of the dialog.

The problem that I have is that the first panel doesn't refresh or update its contents, when I add or remove controls with the buttons.

I tried to invalidate the panel when the events of the buttons are triggered, but it doesn't work.

This is how it looks in run-time:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ended up leaving the groupbox inside the panel, (the opposite of what I was doing before) and added the controls to the groupbox instead of the panel. Then I set in the groupbox `AutoSize = true` and in the panel `AutoScroll = true`.

Now it works perfect!

[image]

Comment: Us a double-buffered panel: `class DblBufPanel { public DblBufPanel() {DoubleBuffered = true; } } `